# Relative layout with grouped vertical align

Tags: android, view, alignment, android-relativelayout, vertical-alignment

I have relative layout. How I can do grouped vertical align as this:

[image: http://s019.radikal.ru/i610/1209/a2/8dead85f60a3.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I think your way is not right for me. I do not show at picture, but some edittext can have more than one line height.
Now what I do. I iterator all textviews, find biggest width and set for all them this width.

Comment: If you use "wrap_content" in the width of each LinearLayout you don't need to do that and the solution is way more simple and easier to mantain.

Comment: Yes, you right, but if layout have a lot of textviews/edittexts, we can get problems. Because, for example, 1.5 have limitation about max count containers (LinearLayout) in layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code would help..

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/Editmessage1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/Textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/Editmessage2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message1" />



</LinearLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Similarly, add another Linear Layout and it should be fine. Or you can align the Linear Layout's orientation Vertical, and align them left and right. And if you are using Eclipse Emulator, I think it will be easier if you refer to graphic design, everytime you change the XML code.

For more info on alignments, refer the following links.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

you can vary the weights as you want. to make textview short and edit text long and vice versa.